# How to map a stored procedure's resulting data to the output dataset

Tags: azure-data-factory

Is it possible to map a stored procedure's resulting data to the output dataset using data factory.

I have the following:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://datafactories.schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-09-01/Microsoft.DataFactory.Pipeline.json",
  "name": "GetViewsByDateRange",
  "properties": {
    "description": "Some description here",
    "activities": [
      {
        "name": "Stored Procedure Activity Template",
        "type": "SqlServerStoredProcedure",
        "inputs": [
          {
            "name": "InputDataset"
          }
        ],
        "outputs": [
          {
            "name": "OutputDataset"
          }
        ],
        "typeProperties": {
          "storedProcedureName": "GetViewsByDateRange",
          "storedProcedureParameters": {
            "startdateid": "20170421",
            "enddateid": "20170514"
          },
          "translator": {
            "type": "TabularTranslator",
            "ColumnMappings": "Id: Test_Id, ViewCount: TestViews"
          }
        },
        "policy": {
          "concurrency": 1,
          "executionPriorityOrder": "OldestFirst",
          "retry": 3,
          "timeout": "01:00:00"
        },
        "scheduler": {
          "frequency": "Minute",
          "interval": "15"
        }
      }
    ],
    "start": "2017-05-05T00:00:00Z",
    "end": "2017-05-05T00:00:00Z"
  }
}
```

But it returns this error:

> 15/05/2017 15:57:09- Failed to Create Pipeline GetViewsByDateRange
>   test-guid-test "message":"Input is malformed. Reason:
>   batchPipelineRequest.typeProperties.translator : Could not find member
>   'translator' on object of type 'SprocActivityParameters'. Path
>   'typeProperties.translator'.. ","code":"InputIsMalformedDetailed"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid this is not supported. You will have to dump the result to storage for further process.

Comment: If the column names in the stored procedure being used as input dataset are the same as the output dataset table, will that work?